# Map angles to a 0-1 range

Tags: math, geometry, angle

Let's say you have two angles, and you label them 0 and 1. Then you have another angle x. You also know if you'll be going Clockwise or Counter Clockwise to get from angle 0 to angle 1. How do you calculate a number that can describe that third angle?

Examples:

| Angle at 0 | Angle at 1 | Rotation Direction | Target Angle | Mapped number (x) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0° | 90° | CCW | 60° | 2/3 |
| 90° | 0° | CW | 60° | 1/3 |
| 0° | 180° | CW | 90° | 1.5 |
| 0° | 180° | CCW | 90° | 0.5 |

Problems I'm having:

- When x can't be supported within 0 and 1 (I am fine with it just telling me it couldn't do it, but having the number would be cooler).
- When switching from Counter-Clock-Wise (CCW) to CW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check](https://ideone.com/SYVSfs) the next approach:

```
def ratio(x, a, b, dircw = False):
    if dircw:
        if x > a:
            x -= 360
        if b > a:
            b -= 360
    else:
        if b < a:
            b += 360
        if x < a:
            x += 360

    return (x-a)/(b-a)


print(ratio(60, 0, 90))
print(ratio(60, 0, 90, True))
print(ratio(60, 90, 0, True))
print(ratio(90, 0, 180, True))
print(ratio(90, 0, 180))

0.6666666666666666
1.1111111111111112
0.3333333333333333
1.5
0.5
```

We consider solution of linear equation (solve inverse of `linear interpolation`)

```
x = a*(1-t) + b*t
```

for unknown `t`.

We have to make normalization to provide `b after a` in cyclic manner in both directions - so `b+-` correction.

To get only positive results, we normalize also `x`.

Comment: Can you explain why this program works? Because it's a little confusing to read. Thanks. @MBo

Comment: I noticed, I got a bit confused because of rotation. Yeah it's fine. I thought I deleted that comment though.